# ASP II7 session is null between two pages

Tags: session, iis, asp-classic, string

I am having session null between two pages.

one.asp

```
<%
 session("one") ="x"
 response.write session("one") ' this prints out x
 %>
```

if I call two.asp after one.asp

two.asp

```
<%
 response.write session("one") ' this prints out nothing
 %>
```

nothing is printed out. It's not a cache problem.
Indeed, this happens  only
if I call the pages with a new host name I set in binding in IIS
(I am using IIS7 on windows server 2008)

```
http://newhostname/one.asp and http://newhostname/two.asp
```

In case I use my machine  name

```
http://mymachine/one.asp and http://mymachine/two.asp
```

all works fine and page two.asp prints out x as expected

Do you know what the problem could be?
Thanks

Comment: It seems that in newhostname there is an underscore in newhostname  and that could cause problems according to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303579/session-lost-when-using-hostname-instead-of-ip-address-ie . I'll write more when I get my administrator change the DNS reference

Comment: Are the pages within same forder/project. If you redirect your page to another server or close your browser then this might happen

Answer (score 0):

If the page has been idle for a long time before `two.asp` is being pulled, then the session might have been expired.

If the browser has been closed, the session identification has been changed, which causes the session to be closed.

If the two pages are on different domains (including subdomains), they doesn't have the same session identification, which cases the session to never have existed for `two.asp`

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7). For information about navigating to locations in the UI, see Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).

In Features View, double-click ASP.
On the ASP page, under Services, expand Session Properties.

Select True from the Enable Session State drop-down list.

In the Actions pane, click Apply.